# Regular Expressions

Tags: rebus, english, computer-puzzle

```
/straw$/;                     # (3,5,5)

/\d+safety\d+/;               # (6,6,2,7)

/^\@[67]+$/;                  # (10,2,2,5,3,6)

/(my |the high)way/;          # (2,3,2,3,7)

/(Thomas|Richard|Harold)/g;   # (5,3,4,3,5)

my $mouth =~ s/\b\w+\b//g;    # (4,3,5,3,2,2,5)

s/it// || s/it/$&/;           # (4,2,2,5,2)

assert(/(way.*){2}way/);      # (6,6,1,5,3)

s/lehill/untain/;             # (4,1,8,3,2,1,8)
```

Comment: Is this an xkcd title entry?

Comment: @noedne, [yup.](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6353/36023)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

/straw$/;                     # (3,5,5)

> The final straw.

/\d+safety\d+/;               # (6,6,2,7)

> There's safety in numbers.

/^\@[67]+$/;                  # (10,2,2,5,3,6)

> ?????????? is at sixes and sevens. [EDIT: "Everything," courtesy of Phylyp.]

/(my |the high)way/;          # (2,3,2,3,7)

> My way or the highway.

/(Thomas|Richard|Harold)/g;   # (5,3,4,3,5)

> Every Tom, Dick, and Harry.

my $mouth =~ s/\b\w+\b//g;    # (4,3,5,3,2,2,5)

> Took the words right out of my mouth.

s/it// || s/it/$1/;           # (4,2,2,5,2)

> Take it or leave it.

assert(/(way.*){2}way/);      # (6,6,1,5,3)

> There's always a third way.

s/lehill/untain/;             # (4,1,8,3,2,1,8)

> Make a mountain out of a molehill.

Comment: From Phylyp's answer, your missing word could be 'rirelguvat', as in 'rirelguvat vf ng fvkrf naq friraf'.

Comment: @Phylyp Thanks for fixing my disregard for the enumeration.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL I considered that but I wasn't sure it was still a common phrase with that word added. I guess it does fit though.

Comment: To be honest, I'd only heard of the expression with the last four words, I had to resort to Google to get the first two words.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty much it. In retrospect, I probably should have done a couple of thing differently (e.g. the "everything" bit), and there's at least one obvious bug in my code, but looks like you managed to plow through all of that, and got everything correct. Nicely done! (All of you!)

Comment: @Bass I was very impressed with how well the clues fit. Most were obscured enough that merely glancing at the clue gave little insight, but reasoning about the regex would lead to saying the answer out loud and the wonderful "a-ha" moment.

Comment: I echo what noedne said, @Bass , a very nicely constructed puzzle.

Comment: Can you explain what are the numbers after the regexes are? It seems like the regexes themselves are sufficient to come up with the solutions?

Comment: @Sweeper, they are an extra hint, and they also make the answers more or less unique. I borrowed the format from crossword puzzles: the numbers indicate the letter count of each word in the answer.

Comment: @Sweeper I thought the first one was "the *last* straw" but the numbers make it clear it's "the final straw."

Comment: Another comment to say this was very enjoyable, thank you @Bass. The `assert(/(way.*){2}way/); ` is the only one that felt a bit weird to me; while it technically fits, somehow it doesn't feel as elegant as the other ones. And, I think the one before that should be `s/it// || s/(it)/$1/;`, seeing the capture group reference without any captures confused me at first.

Comment: @sundar thanks, and I completely agree. The missing capture group is the obvious bug I was talking about in the comment above, replacing the `$1` with `$&` was how I intended to fix it, but since it already got fixed by the solvers' excellent DWIM parsers, I left it as it is; now it kind of reflects the mouseover text in the [original strip](https://xkcd.com/208/) :-)

Answer (score 10):

Partial answer

```
/straw$/;                     # (3, 5, 5)
```

> The final straw

```
/^\@[67]+$/;                  # (10,2,2,5,3,6)
```

> Everything is at sixes or sevens

```
/(my |the high)way/;          # (2,3,2,3,7)
```

> My way or the highway

```
s/it// || s/it/$1/;           # (4,2,2,5,2)
```

> Take it or leave it

```
s/lehill/untain/;             # (4,1,8,3,2,1,8)
```

> Make a mountain out of a molehill

Comment: 7 is znxr vg be oernx vg

Comment: Could be 'Gnxr vg be yrnir vg' like noedne's answer.

Answer (score 4):

(Not sure about line 8)

1.

> the final straw

2.

> there's safety in numbers

3.

> everything is at sixes and sevens

4.

> my way or the highway

5.

> every Tom, Rich and Harry

6.

> took the words out of my mouth

7.

> take it or leave it

8.

> assert itself the right way (?)

9.

> make a mountain of a molehill

---

PS. 8. (courtesy of @noedne)

> there's always a third way

Comment: I was wrong about 8. Thought "assert" was part of the saying.

Comment: In number 5, isn't Dick the more commonly used abbreviation for Richard?

Comment: I knew the idiom "every Tom, Dick and Harry", but I didn't know Dick was a diminutive of Richard, so I searched for "Rich" instead.

Comment: @Nautilus - I first recall my confusion when as a child I read Enid Blyton's _Famous Five_, and was confused when the character named Dick gave his name as Richard to an authority figure. Took me years to figure it out, in those pre-Internet days (my country doesn't use Western names).